# Swift Sequence of actions for one of many nodes of the same name

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I've stuck with creating sequence of SKActions for specific node

```
func addNode() {
  let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "imageName")
  node. //allOtherProporties
  self.addChild(node)

  //setting up actions for created node

  let action1 = SKAction.run {
    //First action in sequence
  }

  let action2 = SKAction.wait(forDuration:2.5)

  let action3 = SKAction.run {
    //Third action in sequence
  }

  node.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([action1,action2,action3])))

}
```

What I want is that every created node is looping inside created for it set of actions. In fact, the first action is done by correct node, and another ones are executed randomly by other nodes... How to stick up a sequence of actions to exactly one and the same node?

Comment: How about introduce [skaction] array. Then you pick a random one

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but IMHO it doesn't change anything if'll append every single action to an array and later on will use it inside a sequence... What I want is that every created node will use forever repeated sequence of actions and right now every action is executed only by a node that was created as the last one...

Comment: node.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([action1,action2,actions[Int.random()]])))

Comment: so when you call `addNode()` to add a new node, the newly added one gets the actions and the previously added node stops executing the actions?

Comment: That is my problem Steve... Lets say if I have 10 nodes, the 10th node execute the sequence ten times and previous 9 nodes do nothing... If its changing anything, action1 is creating a childnode and attaching it to node [let child = SKSpriteNode ; node.addchild(child)]. Maybe the problem is with node.addchild(child)? Sequence is executed by a correct node but its adding a Childs not to itself but only to newly added one? To sum up, 10th node is spawning Childs all the time, and previous ones do nothing. Any clue?

Comment: So maybe my question should be how to target exactly one node of the same class and the same name? enumerateChildNodes(withName: "nodeName" also doesn't solve the problem because its touches every nodes and not exactly the one I want to find...

Comment: Found a glitch in my code. The issue was that in my code node was declared outside the function. If its exactly as in question code everything works well.  Every new function() call should create a new node. Anyway thx guys for Your efforts